# Fetching data with AJAX call, click handler causing issues displaying info

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance

## Where I'm At

I'm making a form for an online silent auction. People click a button, choose one of six fixed amounts `$10, $25, $50, $100, $250, $500` and that amount gets added to the last bid, giving us total amount of their new bid.

## Problem

It takes an extraordinarily long time (4-5 seconds after the button is clicked) to replace the tk-amount placeholder using`.html` to `.current__amount` and `.new__amount` and display these two pieces of data grabbed from a Google Spreadsheet using an AJAX call to the [SheetsU](https://sheetsu.com) API.

*I have a feeling it's because of how much stuff is being done everytime a button is clicked. Is there a better way to approach this?*

### scripts.js

```
// Bid Options
    $(".button__form").on('click', function(){
        var btnSelected = $(this).hasClass("is-selected");
        var sectionOneCompleted = $(".check--one").hasClass("is-completed");

        if (btnSelected) {
            $(this).removeClass("is-selected");
            $(".check--one").css("color", "#ccc");
        } else {
            $(".button__form").removeClass("is-selected");
            $(this).addClass("is-selected");
            $(".check--one").css("color", "#ffdc00");
        }
    });

    $(".button__form").on("click", function() {
        var lastbtnClicked = ($(this).attr("class"));

        // Bid Options
        var buttonOne = $(this).hasClass("button__one");
        var buttonTwo = $(this).hasClass("button__two");
        var buttonThree = $(this).hasClass("button__three");
        var buttonFour = $(this).hasClass("button__four");
        var buttonFive = $(this).hasClass("button__six");
        var buttonSix = $(this).hasClass("button__six");

        // Bid Values
        var buttonOneValue = 10;
        var buttonTwoValue = 25;
        var buttonThreeValue = 50;
        var buttonFourValue = 100;
        var buttonFiveValue = 250;
        var buttonSixValue = 500;

        /*-------------------------------------
        API: SHEETSU
        --------------------------------------*/

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://sheetsu.com/apis/4a8eceba",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "json"
        }).then(function(spreadsheet) {

            // Get and print data
            var currentBid = parseInt(spreadsheet.result.pop().Bids);
            console.log(currentBid);

            var phoneNumber = "1" + spreadsheet.result.pop()["Phone Number"];
            var printBid = $(".current__amount").html("$" + currentBid);
            console.log(printBid);

            if (buttonOne) {
                $(".new__amount").html("$" + (currentBid + buttonOneValue));
            } else if (buttonTwo) {
                $(".new__amount").html("$" + (currentBid + buttonTwoValue));
            } else if (buttonThree) {
                $(".new__amount").html("$" + (currentBid + buttonThreeValue));
            } else if (buttonFour) {
                $(".new__amount").html("$" + (currentBid + buttonFourValue));
            } else if (buttonFive) {
                $(".new__amount").html("$" + (currentBid + buttonFiveValue));
            } else if (buttonSix) {
                $(".new__amount").html("$" + (currentBid + buttonSixValue));
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets go one by one

Take these out of callback, no need to reinitialize for every click.

```
// Bid Values
var buttonOneValue = 10;
var buttonTwoValue = 25;
var buttonThreeValue = 50;
var buttonFourValue = 100;
var buttonFiveValue = 250;
var buttonSixValue = 500;
```

Reduce below

```
 $(".button__form").on('click', function(){
        var btnSelected = $(this).hasClass("is-selected");
        var sectionOneCompleted = $(".check--one").hasClass("is-completed");

        if (btnSelected) {
            $(this).removeClass("is-selected");
            $(".check--one").css("color", "#ccc");
        } else {
            $(".button__form").removeClass("is-selected");
            $(this).addClass("is-selected");
            $(".check--one").css("color", "#ffdc00");
        }
    });
```

to this

```
 $(".button__form").on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("is-selected");
        $(".check--one").toggleClass("is-completed");
    });
//And adjust the color of .check--one in css
```

And use the class property efficiently

```
    if (buttonOne) {
        $(".new__amount").html("$" + (currentBid + buttonOneValue));
    } else if (buttonTwo) {
        $(".new__amount").html("$" + (currentBid + buttonTwoValue));
    } else if (buttonThree) {
        $(".new__amount").html("$" + (currentBid + buttonThreeValue));
    } else if (buttonFour) {
        $(".new__amount").html("$" + (currentBid + buttonFourValue));
    } else if (buttonFive) {
        $(".new__amount").html("$" + (currentBid + buttonFiveValue));
    } else if (buttonSix) {
        $(".new__amount").html("$" + (currentBid + buttonSixValue));
    }
```

to something like this in for loop

```
$(".new__amount."+buttons[i].class).html("$" + (currentBid + buttons[i].value));

var buttons = [{class:"buttonSix", value:123},....]
```

So at last your code could look like this.

```
// Bid Options
var buttons = [{class:"buttonOne", value:12},....{class:"buttonSix", value:123}]
$(".button__form").on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("is-selected");
        $(".check--one").toggleClass("is-completed");
       //And adjust the color of .check--one in css

    var lastbtnClicked = ($(this).attr("class"));

    /*-------------------------------------
    API: SHEETSU
    --------------------------------------*/

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://sheetsu.com/apis/4a8eceba",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json"
    }).then(function(spreadsheet) {

        // Get and print data
        var currentBid = parseInt(spreadsheet.result.pop().Bids);
        console.log(currentBid);

        var phoneNumber = "1" + spreadsheet.result.pop()["Phone Number"];
        var printBid = $(".current__amount").html("$" + currentBid);
        console.log(printBid);
        var $btnForm = $(".button__form")
        for(){
            if($btnForm.hasClass(buttons[i].class)){
               $(".new__amount.").html("$" + (currentBid + buttons[i].value));
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for such a detailed answer, I'm just trying to understand what's happening in the for loop.

Comment: In for loop, its simply displaying value if both classes are present.. oh my mistake. it seems its not right.. give me a min

Comment: I noticed that this section of the `for() loop` didn't have anything passed in it? Does it not need to have something like for(i = 0; i < 1; i++)

Comment: yes.. that was so obvious that, I skipped. kept a pseudo code.

Comment: I'm doing  `for(i = 0; i < buttons.length ; i++){
             if ($btnForm.hasClass(buttons[i].class)){
              var newBid = $(".new__amount").html("$" + (currentBid + buttons[i].value));
              console.log(newBid);
             }` And I don't see anything being printed to the console?

Comment: Please go through `.html` API, `.html()` returns jQuery object, in this case `$(".new__amount")`

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure your "performance issues" arn't actually caused by your http request taking 4-5 seconds to complete? To check open your browsers console and click on the network tab. Then press your button. You should see a request send out and how long it takes to complete.